# Can UNIANOVA command produce plots of main effects and interaction?

Tags: spss

What might I add to this syntax to plot the main effects and interaction?

```
UNIANOVA grade BY gender school
/RANDOM=school
/METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
/INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
/PRINT ETASQ DESCRIPTIVE HOMOGENEITY
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
/DESIGN=gender school gender*school.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
UNIANOVA grade BY gender school
 /RANDOM=school
 /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
 /INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
 /PLOT=PROFILE(school gender school*gender) TYPE=LINE ERRORBAR=NO MEANREFERENCE=NO YAXIS=AUTO
 /PRINT ETASQ DESCRIPTIVE HOMOGENEITY
 /CRITERIA=ALPHA(0.05)
 /DESIGN=gender school gender*school.
```